# What's the difference between tar.gz and tar.Z?

Tags: tar, compression

The downloads on [this page](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/downloads/netcdf/index.jsp), e.g. [of NetCDF C/C++/Fortran 4.1.3](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/downloads/netcdf/netcdf-4_1_3/index.jsp), show `tar.Z` and `tar.gz` formats. The `tar.Z` doesn't even have a configure file in it. What is it used for?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

.Z files are compressed with the older `compress` utility while .gz are compressed with `gzip`.

Some ancient systems might be missing `gzip`/`gunzip` so will use `uncompress` and .Z files.

Comment: However, one should not just rely on the name! Use the `file` program to determine the real type of the file.

Comment: Some very, very, VERY ancient systems that haven't seen an update in two decades...

Comment: That's what I meant with ancient. For example Solaris 7 11/99 was the last Solaris release not bundling gzip.

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17573/whats-the-difference-between-tar-gz-and-tar-z/17582#17582) is the right answer.  I'l just add that although they are compressed using a different program, `gzip`/`gunzip` can decompress .Z archives without any problems.